# AngularJS $promise executes only once

Tags: angularjs

Is any way that $promise can **execute multiple times** or any alternate in angular.

Refer below code.
Sample Code:-

```
promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}

...

if () {
     resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
} else {
     reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it will only execute only once, might be in angularJS you will not get alternative. You can try jQuery or some thing else. :)

Comment: yes, but I want this to complete only using angularJS

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the notify callback

> notify(value) - provides updates on the status of the promise's execution. This may be called multiple times before the promise is either resolved or rejected.

The following (untested) code should notify ten times with the numbers 1-10 and then resolve with the message "Done counting".

```
function countToTen() {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
        for (var counter=1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                notify(counter);
            }, 1000 * counter);
        }
        setTimeout(function() { resolve("Done counting"); }, 10001);
    });
}
```

---

Edit : as ARedHerring notices, notify isn't part of any promise standard and should be considered bad practice.

Comment: please get me any idea or sample code, by using that I can understand concept more :)

Comment: @ChetanSharma I've never used it so I'm not too sure but it is meant to track progress of the resolution of a promise. For example if you are downloading a file it will eventually succeed (resolve) or fail (reject). In the meantime, the progress can be updated by the mean of notify, which can be called multiple times to update the progress. I'll try to put up some code. However as other said, I'm not too sure it is a good idea to use your promise multiple times. Could you maybe add some context to your question?

Comment: @ChetanSharma added an example

Comment: The only problem with this is that OP will have to manually implement the notify functionality into his promise, and that the notify mechanic is non-standard behaviour. I think OP is trying to use the wrong tool for the job and should instead look into a library like highlandjs which is perfect for streams (which appears to be what he is trying to create).

Comment: @ARedHerring can you elaborate on how the notify mechanic isn't standard? While I agree OP might not be looking for the right tool, notify is well defined on both angular's deferred API and promise API.

Comment: Angular's Deferred/Promise API is [not part of the A+ promise spec](https://promisesaplus.com/), which is what I am referring to. Deferred is [considered an anti pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) for one, and having A+ compliant promise behaviour makes your application easier to reason about and interop with other libraries without any extra magic. I would avoid using `notify` for the same reason I avoid using `success`/`error` on http promises.

Comment: TLDR my point is if you're going to use something that looks and walks like a duck, it would be wise to make sure it quacks like a duck instead of barks like a dog.

Comment: @ARedHerring thank you for the answer, I'm only doing web development in my spare time and did not know of the A+ promise spec. I'll make sure to check it out !

Comment: Thanks for sharing idea on it, let me try it :)

Answer (score 0):

The contract of a promise is that it will only ever resolve once, and honestly I can't really imagine any scenarios where it makes sense for it to execute more than once. After a promise has resolved, any subsequent calls to `then` will be invoked upon the next event loop tick as the value of the promise has already been resolved and will be cached.

This seems like an XY problem. Could you explain what you are trying to do in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Oh3x9oFAtpU) where Thomas has told how you can resolving a promise multiple times.

```
$rootScope.$apply( function() {
  deferred.resolve( incremented );
});
```